# Laravel 5.6 How to redirect to a mobile app url?

Tags: php, laravel

I am having difficulties to implement a redirect with `Laravel 5.6` to a mobile app url.
So the idea is that `API` handles a request and based on user agent it redirects to either `android` or `ios` app.

Controller

```
/**
* Reset password redirect logic.
* Redirect user to either android or iphone app based on http user agent.
*
* @param RedirectRequest $request
* @return RedirectResponse
*/
public function redirect(RedirectRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $rememberToken = $request->get('rememberToken');
    $userAgent = $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT');

    if (strpos(strtolower( $userAgent ), 'iphone' ) !== false) {
        return redirect()->to(
            env('FORGET_PASSWORD_IOS_URL') . '?$email=' . $email . '&rememberToken=' . $rememberToken
        );
    } else if (strpos(strtolower( $userAgent ), 'android' ) !== false) {
        return redirect()->to(
            env('FORGET_PASSWORD_ANDROID_URL') . '?$email=' . $email . '&rememberToken=' . $rememberToken
        );
    }
}
```

.env

```
# URL SCHEMA FROM MOBILE APP DEVELOPERS.
FORGET_PASSWORD_IOS_URL=mobileapp://
FORGET_PASSWORD_ANDROID_URL=mobileapp://
```

So the idea behind this, is that when a user requests a password reset from the mobile app, they get an email and that email will contain a link to api. Once user visits a link, they will be redirected to either android or ios app to continue.

The link user receives in email looks like this. `http://api.url.com/password-reset?email=<email>&rememberToken=<TOKEN>`

After user visits the url I expect the result to be in the browser.

`mobileapp://?email=me@email.com&rememberToken=<TOKEN>`

The actual result.

`http://api.url.com/mobileapp:?email=me@email.com&rememberToken=<TOKEN>`

Anyone encountered this before? Or any advices?

Comment: Add slash first and check once FORGET_PASSWORD_IOS_URL=/mobileapp://

Comment: unfortunately same result.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I've added 2 slashes and it worked.

Comment: Actually yes in your case it should be 2 slashes

Answer (score 2):

you should use this method:

```php
$url = env('FORGET_PASSWORD_IOS_URL') . '?$email=' . $email . '&rememberToken=' . $rememberToken;

return redirect()->away($url);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately it gives the same result.

Comment: are you sure that you env return this string: ``mobileapp://`` ?

Comment: I am using Laravel ^7 and if you do not provide URL scheme it does not add anything like http or https. So definitely it works with away method.